# How to do monitoring of an application server

Tags: performance, web-services, monitoring, application-server

There are few services developed and hosted on jetty vergo and jboss server, now I have to monitor and finetune the application. I have to drill down upto code level so that I can find out which service method is taking how many `CPU cycle`, `memory usage` etc? what are the tools available or is there anyway I can drill down to code level using `jvisualvm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, there are several options, my preferred are:

- RHQ http://www.jboss.org/rhq
- https://github.com/jmxtrans/jmxtrans

If you really need to drill down, you can use tools like AppDynamics http://www.appdynamics.com/ (there's a free version).

Comment: I have one more question, how to drill down to code level using jconsole?

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible, because tools like Jmxtrans or JConsole are using JMX to get metrics data, but it is not possible to match metrics like CPU usage to code blocks on this level. If you want to drill down to code level and do real profiling, you have to use tools like AppDynamics, JProfiler or VisualVM. Here is a InfoQ-article describing how to do this with OpenSource tools http://www.infoq.com/articles/java-profiling-with-open-source

Answer (score -1):

Do you really need to create  code as it is time consuming? May be it is going to be still to find a tool that is able to do it for you. I am not but have a look at the software that is called [Anturis](http://www.anturis.com). I know  that it can monitor various types of servers and so on. I have provided a link for you to consider it.

Comment: thnx user, I will take a look at it :)